# How to prevent full-screen applications from minimizing when clicking on a different monitor?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, and I still have much to learn. However, I am completely new to multi-monitor setups on any platform.

I have two monitors, a 1440x900 acting as my main monitor and a 1024x768 to the left of the monitor; I am using the GTX 960 GPU. Whenever I start a full-screen application or game, for instance CS:GO, and have it running full-screen on my main monitor, upon clicking on the smaller monitor causes the game to minimize, as well as default the mouse's position the center of the main monitor.

Is there anyway to force the application to remain fullscreen, without running it in full-screen windowed, when performing tasks in another monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line:

```
export SDL_VIDEO_MINIMIZE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS=0
```

to **/etc/environment** and reboot.